# android buttons and image in the same page

Tags: image, button, android-activity, view, imageview

I have to create a button to show an image. I created it using two activity, but I want that the button and the image view stay in the same page. So, I think I have to create only one activity, right? can you explain hot to do this? this is my code:

ACTIVITY ONE:

```
public class HomeWork extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_work);

        Button getResultButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        getResultButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent resultIntent =new Intent(HomeWork.this,HomeWork2.class);

                startActivity(resultIntent);
            }

        });
}
```

SECOND ACTIVITY:

```
public class HomeWork2 extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_work2);

    ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.apple);
}
```

the apk works correctly, the only problem is that I want button and imageview in the same image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a layout which contains both the Button and the ImageView.

Then in the Button's click listener, use

```
ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.apple);
```

instead of

```
Intent resultIntent =new Intent(HomeWork.this,HomeWork2.class);
startActivity(resultIntent);
```

Also remove (the now unused) HomeWork2 from your manifest.

**[EDIT]**

---

You may add more buttons, to change the contents of the ImageView.
You only have to put in their click listeners:

```
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orange);
```

or

```
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pineapple);
```

or ...